# Compiling with a reference to a TLB (32Bit and 64Bit reference path differences)

Tags: vb.net, vb6, typelib

I have a VB6 application that connects to a Type Library (.TLB).  The .TLB is stored in the Syswow64 folder on my development PC (because it is a 64 bit machine), however it is stored in the System32 folder on the live server (because it is a 32 bit machine).

How do I change the reference to the System32 folder before/after compiling the VB application?

The Type Library exposes types in a VB.NET DLL.

Comment: Stop putting stuff in operating system directories.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I agree.  However, I am only able to add references to files in the SYSWOW64 folder.  The reference does not appear if I try to add a reference from another folder.

Comment: Why is the vb.net tag used in your question?  Does this have anything to do with VB.NET?  If it does not, your tag will through off the answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 0):

You should recreate the type library in the application folder:

- Start a command prompt with Visual Studio tools by going to  Start=>All Programs=>Microsoft Visual Studio xx=>Visual Studio Tools=>Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)
- Use CD to get to the application folder (with the VB.NET DLL in it).
- Type: REGASM <assemblyname.dll> /tlb:<assemblyname.tlb> /codebase

Now add the reference to VB6.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing happens when I try to add a reference to a file that is contained in any directory except: syswow64. There is no error and no reference appears.  There is already a reference to the file in question to syswow64 but I cannot get rid of it.

Comment: Try first unregistering using: REGTLIB -u <assemblyname.tlb>

Comment: What, the unregistering?